# adding times to autofill a field VBA MSAccess

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am making a booking system on MSAccess using VBA. On my form I have fields for creating a new booking which is then to be added to a database on SQL server. I have a combo box set up to allow the user to select and activity and it then fills out the ID of the activity and the duration of the activity. This duration is a number 1 or 2 or 3 etc for how many hours the activity takes.

However my question relates to calculating a finish time for the user. I wish the finish time textbox to be auto filled out when the user selects a start time from a list of times for example, 9:00:00 (To match the format the times are stored on the sql server) and having selected an activity by adding these together. So far I have tried something like this.

```
    Me.txtFinishTime.Text = Me.cmbStartTime.Value + Me.txtDuration.Value
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateadd-function

Comment: Are the start times always *on the hour*? In which case you could display 9 to represent 9am and just add 1,2 to this numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be:

```
Me!txtFinishTime.Value = DateAdd("h", Me!txtDuration.Value, CDate(Me!cmbStartTime.Value))
```